# Rubik Cube having cubies of exactly 2 colors

Tags: combinatorics, elementary-number-theory

Rubik’s cube is a $3\times3\times3$ cube which has $6$ different colors for each face. The Rubik’s cube is made from $26$ smaller pieces which are called cubies. There are $6$ cubies at the centre of each face and these comprise of a single color. There are $8$ cubies at the $8$ corners which comprise of exactly $3$ colors. The $12$ remaining cubies comprise of exactly $2$ colors.

Suppose we have a variation of the Rubik’s Cube, it’s the Rubik’s cuboid which has different colors on its $6$ faces. The Rubik’s Cuboid comes in various sizes represented by $M \times N \times O$, $M,N,O \in \mathbb{N}$. We need to tell, in a Rubik’s cuboid with arbitrary dimensions, how many cubies would be there, which comprise of exactly $2$ colors?

**Example**: Say for $M=3 , N=3$ and $O=3$ answer is $12$.

Comment: So you want to count the edge cubies? Two questions you need to answer: How many edges are there? How does the 'length' of an edge determine the number of edge cubies it has? Answer those, and it should be easy to come up with the formula.

Comment: @JustinBenfield Total cubies which comprise of exactly 2 colors. And by how many edges what you mean ? Its a cube.And length of edge adgain does not matter, as its a cube all edges are of same length and each cubie is of same size.

Comment: The length of the edge of the cuboid is the number of cubbies on that edge

Comment: It's not a Cube, but a Rectangular Prism (this is because $M$, $N$, and $O$ may be different from each other). How many edges does a Rectangular Prism have (same number as an actual Cube btw)? So along one of those edges, how many edge cubies (2 colors on them) will there be? (It's not as large as the length in number of total cubies of that edge, why?)

Comment: Why are we paying pilgrimage to Ernő Rubik at all here?

Comment: @JustinBenfield Ohh sorry, my bad :)

Comment: @IrregularUser Is it wrong to pay pilgrimage to Erno Rubik ?

Comment: @mat7 In terms of general $M \times N \times O$ cuboids, the Rubik brand has only made the $2 \times 2 \times 4$, which is nothing compared to what other brands have contributed to the cubing world. So in fact, if you specfically refer to the "Rubik Cuboid", then this refers only to the $2 \times 2 \times 4$.

Comment: Are you participating in some coding competition? This and the other question look like them. Especially the $mod$ part.

Comment: @Dhruv Nothing like that. Its a maths problem, and not an algo one

Comment: https://www.codechef.com/INLO2016/problems/INLO22
PLEASE ! :D this is a question from this online competetion

Comment: @ArchitChauhan : Following that link did not take me to a page describing the competition problem. Can you fix it? Or give a link that does not require me to allow strange cookies (if that's what causes my problems). I would like to verify that this is, indeed, a problem from an on-going contest.

Answer (score 0):

First of all we know that we can find the 2 sided cubies only on the edges of a Rubik's Cube. The equation I have mentioned doesn't work for cuboids that have even one of their sides less than one as in that case the number of 2 sided cubies would be 0.

Otherwise, $\text{ number of cubies } = 4\cdot(L+B+H-6)$ where L, B and H stand for length, breadth and height.